# Is there a shortcode for product description in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

Is there any shortcode to call the product description(text field under the title)?

For now, I'm using another custom field to do this job but it will be better if I use the WooCommerce field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrote a very similar solution to @LoicTheAztec's answer above, but slightly more defensively (as his solution was breaking Elementor edits for me due to there not being a product context when it executes the shortcode on save).

It also solves your paragraph/newline issue as the content is formatted (basically replacing newlines with `<p>` tags) before returning.

```
function custom_product_description($atts){
    global $product;

    try {
        if( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
            return wc_format_content( $product->get_description("shortcode") );
        }

        return "Product description shortcode run outside of product context";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return "Product description shortcode encountered an exception";
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'custom_product_description', 'custom_product_description' );
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Did you encounter any problems during long term use? I intend to apply the change in all my posts. I used an ACF to make my content.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the snippet above. How can I also implement this for "Additional Information" and "Reviews"?

Answer (score 14):

You can build your own shortcode this way:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_description', 'display_product_description' );
function display_product_description( $atts ){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => get_the_id(),
    ), $atts, 'product_description' );

    global $product;

    if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product') )
        $product = wc_get_product($atts['id']);

    return $product->get_description();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

**Examples of USAGE** `[product_description]`

1) In the current product page ph:

```
echo do_shortcode( "[product_description]" );
```

2) In any php code providing the related product ID

```
echo do_shortcode( "[product_description id='37']" );
```

Comment: Worked! But the text is no more recognizing 'enter' as a paragraph or break line, just if I use <p> or <br>. Also not recognizing woocomerce shortcode like that "[products class="suggestion" ids="686"]"(this is woocomerce default field..my other custom field is still working)

Comment: @Trooller Just inspect WordPress [the_content()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) and [get_the_content()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) available source code, to add in this shortcode function everything needed to get what you want.